# Switch language layout by Alt+Shift. Problem with next shift+any key for typing text

Tags: keyboard-layout

Alt+Shift works fine at ton of linux distributives. But if you want type a shift+char after layout switch, char still in lower case. How can I fix it?

PS: Try: (Xu,Ku,U)buntu, Elementary OS, Manjaro with Xfce and KDE. Same result.

Comment: Please add more focus to the question, and make it more reproducible. Which DE and which Ubuntu version do you use? How did you set keyboard layout switch in it?

Comment: Current distributions of Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu and etc. I already said it at PS.
Layout switch by standart system gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just discovered 10+ years old bug.

The X server interprets shortcuts on key press, not key release.

I have prepared specially patched Xorg packages to fix this bug in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys).
Packages from it does not work on GNOMEs Hell, but works for many other environments in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (at least in Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce).

Use commands below to add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then reboot. Note this PPA also good for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

---

Optionally pin (lock/hold) related packages to prevent their upgrade with:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xorg-hotkeys
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-nrbrtx-xorg-hotkeys
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

Comment: The OP's problem is probably something else. Setting `Alt+Shift` to switch input languages does at least not prevent me from using the `Shift` key to get capital letters. Can you reproduce the issue as described by OP?

Comment: I have just reproduced it - we need to press `Alt+Shift` to change language, then keep holding `Shift` and try to type character. The character will be lowercase.

Comment: Why would you keep holding it? ;)

Comment: It is more question for OP, but I can confirm it. Can't really say about this habit in my daily life, may be I have using it too while switching by `Ctrl+Shift`.

Comment: Yes, it's more a question for OP. Let's see if he reads this and clarifies.

Comment: I from Russia and use 2 keyboard layer very intensively. And after switch by alt+shift I don't want spend time to unhold my finger from shift if I need Upper case. This works on Windows but still doesn't work on Linux (

Comment: @Nuclear You can simply use my PPA as described in the above answer. But please note that it will not fix the problem for GNOME Shell.

Comment: Tnx alot it works for me. Check it at current version of Elementary OS.

Comment: Nice to hear. So you can accept my answer by clicking check mark in the left of it. Спасибо!

Comment: But when will it be included officially in core? Or fix it?

Comment: It is hard to predict. You can join related discussion [on the community forum](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876). It is really long story, without good signs to official resolution.